# Creating validation check in beforeCreate hook

Tags: sails.js

I have a `user` model which I would like to add some additional validation too.

I am using the `beforeCreate` hook to do my checks, but I am having some trouble figuring out what to do after that.

```
beforeCreate: function(values, callback) {

    UserService.additionalCheck(values, function(err, success){
        if(err){
            return callback(err);
        }
        if(success === true){
            callback();
        }
        else{
            return callback('Did not validate');
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that this results in a `500` status and `Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error`.

All I want to do is send the same kind of response that you get when you have an 'invalidAttribute', how can I accomplish this?

---

TLDR: How can I make my own invalid attribute checks and responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sails documentation covers [custom validation on attributes](http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/concepts/ORM/Validations.html) here. The example below pulls from that documentation. Using the custom validations would mean you don't need to use a beforeCreate hook.

```
// api/models/foo
module.exports = {

  types: {
    is_point: function(geoLocation) {
      return geoLocation.x && geoLocation.y
    },
    password: function(password) {
      return password === this.passwordConfirmation;
    }
  },
  attributes: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      minLength: 5,
      maxLength: 15
    },
    location: {
      //note, that the base type (json) still has to be defined
      type: 'json',
      is_point: true
    },
    password: {
      type: 'string',
      password: true
    },
        passwordConfirmation: {
          type: 'string'
    }

  }
}
```

If you'd also like custom validation messaging, as well as a few Rails like `findOrCreate` type class methods you can use the [Sails Hook Validation](https://github.com/lykmapipo/sails-hook-validation) package. Note that it requires Sails 0.11.0+.